# Shortcut to close tabs with matching URL pattern

Tags: ios, shortcuts-app

In iOS 12 Shortcuts app, is there a way to search through your open tabs, determine any tabs that begin with `www.apple.com` (regardless what’s after the `apple.com`), and close it?

I am looking for a way of quickly closing any tabs that begin with http://www.apple.com?

Something like:

**IF** `www.apple.com/*.*`
**THEN** close tab
**ELSE** end